# How to set API Gateway Description in serverless.yml?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I'm trying to set the description to a REST API Gateway through serverless.yml, using serverless version 2.72.3

I couldn't find anything here https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway

I've also tried:

```
provider:
  apiGateway:
    description: Your custom description
```

but nothing happens after deploying to AWS, the description is not changing (other changes are working)

EDIT: Thanks to [Albert Marrero answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75199544/3684747) I now understand why it isn't working, but not how to make it work. Attached Screenshot to clarify which description I'd like to change (API Gateway description, not stage description)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define `ApiGatewayRestApi` resource by your self ([Ref](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/resources)), then you can add description.

```yaml
provider:
  apiGateway:
    RestApiId:
      Ref: MyApiGateway
    RestApiRootResourceId:
      Fn::GetAtt:
        - MyApiGateway
        - RootResourceId

resources:
  Resources:
    MyApiGateway:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
      Properties:
        Name: my-api-gateway
        Description: My api gateway description # Put your description
```

And remember to update `provider` to use your defined api gateway if you already config http event for some lambda functions

[List of ApiGateway properties](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-restapi.html)

Comment: I like this solution to address the serverless framework lack of description for the API Gateway Rest option. I need to test it out to see if it works on my end.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [guide](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml#api-gateway-v1-rest-api), this setting for the description for the API Gateway stage deployment. Check your description in each of your stages

Comment: Thanks, now I understand which description I'm setting (stage description), but i want to set the API Gateway Description

Comment: From my usage of the serverless framework, I have not seen an option for that. I would recommend setting up the description via a tag.    If you want I can add that to my answer for you to accept as an answer. 

I thought you wanted to know what description option does properly.